# Is there a lightweight library to do draggable+sortable lists inside greasemonkey scripts?

Tags: javascript, list, greasemonkey

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script, as part of which I'd like to sort a list by dragging its items. I'm using mootools, but the component for sortable lists doesn't work in the GM sandboxed environment. Can you recommend a smallish library/piece of code to do list sorting in the most lightweight fashion? I want it to be independant of any large framework and don't feel like implementing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to debug a library such as mootools, instead of @require-ing it, just copy/paste the entire source into your own script. Then you can debug it the same as your own code.

On another note, [this script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/26062) includes the ability to drag-and-drop it's own window around the screen, with no additional library. Maybe you could analyze it and borrow code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any particular issues with just MooTools, but in general you may include external scripts into a GreaseMonkey script.

This has been addressed in previous questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439286/how-to-embed-additional-jquery-plugins-into-greasemonkey), as well as on the [GreaseSpot wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Code_snippets#jQuery_in_Greasemonkey_scripts_using_the_metadata_key_.40require).

Comment: There are issues with the component I need from mootools-more... unfortunately it doesn't work and the way GM reports errors makes it near impossible to debug, as it doesn't tell me the number of the offending line.